# Programmatically set PubSub filter on subscription

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I create a GCP PubSub subscription like that

```
    TopicName topic = TopicName.ofProjectTopicName(projectId, this.topic);
    try {
        client.createSubscription(subscriptionId, topic, PushConfig.getDefaultInstance(), 10);
    } catch (AlreadyExistsException e) {
        // sub is already there. nothing to do
    }
```

Is it programmatically possible to add filters to the subscription? I know its possible in the google console but I would prefer to have it bootstrapped in the code.

Comment: its possible in python library, at least. Which language are you using ? [python-pubsub: add support for filtering](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/85)

Comment: Do you use Java?

Comment: Yes, I use java

Answer (score 1):

Found it out:

```
        Subscription subscription = Subscription.newBuilder()
                .setName("projects/xyz/subscriptions/foo")
                .setTopic(topic.toString())
                .setPushConfig(PushConfig.getDefaultInstance())
                .setAckDeadlineSeconds(10)
                .setFilter("attributes.A = \"a\"")
                .build();
        client.createSubscription(subscription);
```